# Relative Positioning Error with <button> in FF and Chrome

Tags: html, css

I am having a very strange problem here. I tried to create a search bar and this is how it looks in chrome, which is what i want.

[image: in Chrome]

It works fine in Safari, Here is all the involved CSS code.

```
#input {
    height: 25px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    width: 70px;
}
#button {
    margin-left: -6px;
    height:27px;
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

But in case of FireFox, the Button moves up a little which makes it look bad. Here is how it looks in FireFox.

[image: in firefox]

This BUg in Firefox is fixed if i remove the line `top: -2px;` but then a similar problem crops up in Chrome and Safari.

How do i Fix this ?

Comment: get rid of the top:-2px in #button and add border:1px slod transparent; to #input

Comment: Do you really need to place the button by using position property? I'm not sure how the rest of your code looks like but why don't you try use margins if the button needs to be moved around?

Comment: I used the position property in first place, because I was having problems with alignment.

Comment: @Rohit Smith do you use jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix with jQuery

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($.browser.mozilla){
        $("#button").css("top", "-2px")
    }
})
```

If you have not added jQuery add this script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```